# ¿Cómo convertir varios módulos de Python en un solo ejecutable?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pasa que tengo un pequeño sistema de ventas hecho con python tkinter y sqlite3, tengo los archivos que aparecen en la foto y estuve usando pyinstaller para convertir a ejecutable el archivo index ques es el principal donde hago el llamado de todos los modulos o scripts que tengo, pero al terminar la conversion y ejecutar el archivo exe que esta dentro de dist me sale este error.
que es lo que debo hacer, a mi parecer creo que los otros archivos como manager.py, ventanas.py y data.py no se esta ejecuntando... como convierto todos a ejecutable

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: tengo un proyecto que consta de varios archivos.py, eh visto tutoriales de como convertir un archivo.py a un archivo.exe, eh seguido los pasos que indican, pero al finalizar y ejecutar el archivo.exe me sale el error que deje en la captura.
lo que estuve pensando es de si tambien debo convertir a exe los otros archivos.py, en este caso solo convertí a exe el achivo principal donde hago el llamado de los otros archivos